# Checking entries in one list against another list

Tags: excel

Not sure where to even start, or if it is possible to do in excel. The problem:

I have a list of 100 items that is set in stone. On any given day I can get a request to check a value which can be associated with over 1500 items, some of which may be the 100 items on the static list. I would like to create a formula in Cell C1 which will check Column A1:A1500, against whether any entries there appear in Column B1:B100.

Comment: `COUNTIF()`? What have you tried?

Comment: I set up two tables "Static", with numbers 1-10, then the other table, "Test", will be the one that changes. `COUNTIF(Table, Static)` in a separate Cell yields 1; ideally what I would like is some kind of conditional formatting that would highlight those entries in the Test table that match entries in the Static table

Comment: Say your "Test" is the one you want to highlight, and is column A... Say your Static info is in column B.  A conditional format formula of `=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$100,$A1)>0`, then set the Applies To range as `$A$1:$A$100` (or however many rows) should work.